# Debian 10 WIFI not works

Tags: debian, wifi, virtualbox

I installed Debian 10.3 on a removable drive in VirtualBox.

I think that is the reason why the wifi is not working.

Maybe the related packages have been removed.

```
~$ lspci |grep Network
3a:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

How do I get these packages and make wifi work?

Dell xps15 9570, debian10.3; KDE 5.54

Comment: No.I havn't imagined that just a driver is needed. `sudo apt install firmware-atheros`

Answer (score 2):

I thought I need many packages to install, many steps to follow...
search `Debian QCA6174` and I found `firmware-atheros（20190717-2）`

```
sudo apt install firmware-atheros
reboot
```

That's all.